# Create Coloring book page from image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I want to play and learn a little bit with image processing.

I found a page that converts any image to a coloring book sketch and it does this really well.

Original:
[image]
Sketch:
[image]

I would like to rebuild something like this. I looked into OpenCV and thought maybe by highlighting contours/edges that would work.

I got some results with Canny Edge detection:

```
img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
img_blur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img_gray, (3, 3), 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(image=img_gray, threshold1=20, threshold2=100)  # Canny Edge Detection
ret,th2 = cv2.threshold(edges,100,255,cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV)
cv2.imshow('Canny Edge Detection', th2)
```

[image]

My result is not so smooth and detailed. For example, the text, or the face of my cat.
So my question would be, am I on the right path; if yes, what else could I try?

Or do I need to do this with an machine learning model? For that I would need a ton of data I suppose to train the model...

Comment: See https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/df/dac/group__photo__render.html and the link to https://learnopencv.com/non-photorealistic-rendering-using-opencv-python-c/

Answer (score 1):

You can get an image of the sketch with simple openCV techniques. I got the attached image using the following code:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
image = cv2.imread('input_image.jpg')
gray = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
blurred = cv2.GaussianBlur(gray, (5, 5), 0)
edges = cv2.Canny(blurred, 30, 100)
edges_inv = cv2.bitwise_not(edges)
plt.imshow( edges_inv, cmap = 'gray')
```

[image]